# BrowserTest on a multisite gives an error

Tags: 8, testing

My sites directory looks like this:

default, site1, site2, site3.

The default directory is empty. I want to run tests against my site1 database. So I have put its details in phpunit.xml

Here is my phpunit.xml set up.

```
  <php>
    <!-- Set error reporting to E_ALL. -->
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="32767"/>
    <!-- Do not limit the amount of memory tests take to run. -->
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL value: http://localhost -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://d8.site1.dev"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_DB value: mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename#table_prefix -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://site1:site1@localhost/site1"/>
    <!-- Example BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY value: /path/to/webroot/sites/simpletest/browser_output -->
    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value=""/>
  </php>
```

And then my actual test:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\my_module\Functional;

use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;

/**
 * Simple test to ensure that main page loads with module enabled.
 *
 * @group my_module_tests
 */
class LoadTest extends BrowserTestBase {

  /**
   * Modules to enable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = ['my_module'];

  /**
   * A user with permission to administer site configuration.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\user\UserInterface
   */
  protected $user;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->user = $this->drupalCreateUser(['administer site configuration']);
    $this->drupalLogin($this->user);
  }

  /**
   * Tests that the home page loads with a 200 response.
   */
  public function testLoad() {
    $this->drupalGet('node/add/product_list_page');
    $this->assertResponse(200);
  }

}
```

Then from the core directory of Drupal I run:

```
../../vendor/bin/phpunit --group my_module_group
```

Then I get this error:

1) Drupal\Tests\my_module\Functional\LoadTest::testLoad
copy(/var/www/site/docroot/sites/default/default.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Why is it looking in my empty default directory and not site1 for this file?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a multisite directory setup with PHP Unit.

Since your default directory is empty, I suggest creating a symbolic link from the default directory to the site1 directory. You can do that by using commands similar to this one from sites directory.

```
ln -s sites1 default
```

Not sure, but you may also need to adjust the `$sites` variable in sites.php.

Also, make sure you specify a printerClass like this in the last line.

```
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php" colors="true"
         beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutChangesToGlobalState="true"
         checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="false"
         printerClass="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\HtmlOutputPrinter">
```

Here is what my php tag looks like in `phpunit.xml` (I use SQLite though and specify an output directory.) You may need to adjust directory permissions so that it is writable. I test on my remote machine with a FQDN, not sure if that is ideal though.

```
<php>
    <!-- Set error reporting to E_ALL. -->
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="32767"/>
    <!-- Do not limit the amount of memory tests take to run. -->
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL value: http://localhost -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="https://dev.example.com"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_DB value: mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename#table_prefix -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="sqlite://dev.example.com/sites/dev.example.com/files/.ht.sqlite"/>
    <!-- Example BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY value: /path/to/webroot/sites/simpletest/browser_output -->
    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="/path/to/document/root/sites/dev.example.com/files/simpletest/browser_output"/>
</php>
```

Also, I run the phpunit command from the Drupal core directory like this (I do not use group ID but I know it may be possible.

```
sudo -u www-data ../vendor/bin/phpunit ../modules/contrib/example/tests/src/Functional/ExampleHomepageTest.php
```

Here is what my test looks like. It will need the correct directory structure and classname.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\example\Functional;

use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;

/**
 * Tests to ensure Example.com Homepage is reachable
 *
 * @group example_ui
 */
class ExampleHomepageTest extends BrowserTestBase {

/**
 * Modules to enable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected static $modules = ['node', 'user'];

protected $profile = 'standard';

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setUp() {
parent::setUp();

}

/**
  * Tests that the reaction rule listing page works.
  */
public function testHomepage() {

  $account = $this->drupalCreateUser(array('administer site configuration'));
  $this->drupalLogin($account);

  $this->drupalGet('<front>');
  $this->assertSession()->statusCodeEquals(200);
  $this->assertSession()->pageTextContains('cleaning');
 }
}
```

This page will be useful: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit

Comment: If you have to create a symlink from default to the multisite then that must mean phpunit is using sites/default and you can effectively only test against one site, not multiple sites. This is what I am running into right now and it appears phpunit is only looking in sites/default, no matter the URI passed. I will look at setting, sites.php too, that is a good next step.

Comment: sites.php isn't directing the incoming phpunit request to the correct folder after updating sites.php. The hostname was already the same as the sites/foldername.

Comment: We are using <phpunit bootstrap="./docroot/vendor/weitzman/drupal-test-traits/src/bootstrap.php`> so that is a variable.